# replace csv imported data NaN to average value, weight them, and add all

Tags: c#

I am trying to import data from CSV, replacing NaN with average value of row,   weighting them, and adding all A0 ~ A3, B0 ~ B3, C0 ~ C3 to
find average of each A,B,C

weight ABC = 0.25 weight DEF = 0.2 weight GHI = 0.50 weight JKL = 0.05

Sample Data

```
     ABC  DEF  GHI   JKL 
A0    1   NaN   3.7   4      -> Replace NaN => 2.9 
A1   5    6.2  7     8       
A2   9   NaN   7     6      -> Replace NaN => 7.33 
B0   NaN  4    3.5    2      -> Replace NaN => 3.16 
B1   1    2    3     4    
B2   5.3  6    7     8    
C0   9    10   NaN   8     -> Replace NaN => 9 
C1   7    6.7  5     NaN     -> Replace NaN => 6.23 
C2   3    2    1.9   2
```

Process

```
A0 (0.25 + 0.58 + 1.85 + 0.2) = 2.88 
A1 (1.25 + 1.24 + 3.5 + 0.4) = 6.39 
A2 (2.25 + 1.46 + 3.5 + 0.3) = 7.52 
... 
C3( 0.75 + 0.4 + 0.95 + 0.1) = 2.2

     Final 
    Average of A = (2.88 + 6.39 + 7.52) = 5.59 
    Average of B = (3.44 + 2.35 + 6.42) = 4.07 
    Average of C = (9.15 + 5.99 + 2.2) = 5.78
```

Here is what I have so far

```
var values = File.ReadAllLines("TEST.csv")                                         
.Skip(1)
.SelectMany(line => line.Split(','))
.Select(token =>
{
    double value;
    return double.TryParse(token, out value) ? (double?)value : null;
})
.Where( x => !double.IsNaN(x) ).Average();
```

Here I am not getting the values what I want.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: I dont think it is replacing NaN with average of row

Answer (score 0):

I'm using stringreader to read from a string.  You can replace stringreader with streamreader to read from file.  I'm getting a different answer from your code which I think is due to your truncating of decimal places.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication118
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "ABC DEF GHI JKL\n" +
                "A0 1 NaN 3.7 4\n" +
                "A1 5 6.2 7 8\n" +
                "A2 9 NaN 7 6\n" +
                "B0 NaN 4 3.5 2\n" +
                "B1 1 2 3 4\n" +
                "B2 5.3 6 7 8\n" +
                "C0 9 10 NaN 8\n" +
                "C1 7 6.7 5 NaN\n" +
                "C2 3 2 1.9 2\n";

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);

            List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
            string line = "";
            int rowCount = 0;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (rowCount++ >= 1)
                {
                    line = line.Trim();
                    if (line.Length > 0)
                    {
                        Data newData = new Data();
                        data.Add(newData);
                        string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
                        newData.name = splitLine[0];
                        decimal?[] numbers = splitLine.Skip(1).Select(x => (x == "NaN") ? null : (decimal?)decimal.Parse(x)).ToArray();

                        decimal average = (decimal)numbers.Sum() / (decimal)numbers.Where(x => x != null).Count();

                        newData.values = numbers.Select(x => (x == null) ? average : (decimal)x).ToArray();

                    }
                }

            }
            var results = data.GroupBy(x => x.name.Substring(0, 1))
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    group = x.Key,
                    average = x.Average(y => y.getSumWeight)
                }).ToList();


        }

    }
    public class Data
    {
        public static decimal[] weights = { 0.25M, 0.2M, 0.50M, 0.05M };
        public string name { get; set; }
        public decimal[] values { get; set; }

        public decimal getSumWeight { get { return values.Select((x, i) => weights[i] * x).Sum(); } }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 
looks like weights havent been calculated.

newData.values = numbers.Select(x => (x == null) ? average : decimal)x).ToArray(); 

How should I adjust "weight ABC = 0.25 weight DEF = 0.2 weight GHI = 0.50 weight JKL = 0.05" to above code?